# Relay createContainer renderFetched is not passed required props to component

Tags: react-native, relay

i am new to the relay, and excited to work with it, however i got stuck for almost a day with my code and have no idea which has problem, it is very simple code

here is my query route

```
class UserRoute extends Route {
  static paramDefinitions = {
    userId: { required: true }
  };
  static queries = {
    user_by_id: () => Relay.QL`
      query {
        user_by_id(id: $userId)
      }
    `
  };
  static routeName = 'UserRoute';
}
```

here is my component

```
class UserInfo extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('this.props.user', this.props.user_by_id);
    return (
      <Text>name: {this.props.user_by_id.name}</Text>
    )
  }
}
```

and here is the relay container

```
UserInfoRelay = Relay.createContainer(
  UserInfo,
  {
    fragments: {
      user_by_id: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on User {
          name
        }
      `
    }
  }
)
```

and this is my root container

```
<RootContainer
  Component={UserInfoRelay}
  route={new UserRoute({userId: 5})}
  renderFetched={(data) => <UserInfo {...this.props} {...data} />}
/>
```

the returned graphql query was correct

[Log from my relay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niJx8.png)

However i did not get the desired props which is the "name"

[This is props i get from log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0DVW.png)

What did i do wrong? Thank you for any help, for me relay is promising but to jump into is quite bleeding ☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️

Have A Good Day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was change this

```
UserInfoRelay = Relay.createContainer(
  UserInfo,
  {
    fragments: {
      user_by_id: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on User {
          name
        }
      `
    }
  }
)
```

into

```
UserInfo = Relay.createContainer(
  UserInfo,
  {
    fragments: {
      user_by_id: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on User {
          name
        }
      `
    }
  }
)
```

this is indeed help me to get the desired props, but i don't know why, can someone explain this solution

Cheers